# MYSQL Query Complicated I can not solve?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a mysql query that selects the following fields in exmplo, which lists all the Master table, however when the day is already in pt_hini field, it lists all but one! all signed up cad_id in the table ponto.pt_cadid to relate the two! I'm racking my brain for a long time! Grateful to those who help.

Table Cadastro fields ( cad_id, cad_nom)
   Table Ponto fields (pt_id, pt_cadid, pt_hini) * pt_hini type datetime.

```
SELECT c.cad_nom
     , c.cad_id 
  FROM cadastro c
  LEFT 
  JOIN ponto p
    ON c.cad_id = p.pt_cadid   
 WHERE p.pt_hini BETWEEN '2015-03-14 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-14 23:00:00' 
 ORDER 
    BY c.cad_nom;
```

I need List cadastro.cad_id, cadastro.cad_nom, ponto.pt_hini.

This is an input control system of employees , if it has already been released on it will not load the list.

Ex: INSERT INTO (pt_cadid, pt_hini) VALUES (12, '2015-03-14 12:00:15');

ON LIST THE RESULT .All employees will be load, but ID 12 Not !

Comment: You are negating your `outer join` with the `where` critera, but I'm not sure if that's the problem or not.  If you supply sample data and desired results, you might get a better response.

Comment: SELECT cadastro.cad_nom, cadastro.cad_id FROM cadastro LEFT JOIN ponto ON cadastro.cad_id=ponto.pt_cadid   WHERE (ponto.pt_hini  NOT BETWEEN '2015-03-14 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-14 23:00:00') OR ponto.pt_hini = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'   ORDER BY cadastro.cad_nom;   This way it shows all, I need what it show all no data ponto.pt_hini not between !!

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results.  Your query doesn't really make sense.  You are doing a `left join` which keeps everything in the first table -- before applying the `where`.  I can't see what the intention is.

Comment: Now have more details in my question, it's helps? !

Comment: Your present query selects no columns from ponto, which seems odd given the written requirement

Comment: I do a LEFT JOIN to be able to see table point and bring the cad_nom which is a String and not pt_cadid that is only the ID , do not know if this correct